# Sudo su don't ask Password to switch from Sudo user to Root User

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora

In my linux system i have two sudo users and another root. When i want to switch from sudo user to Root user, and put command SU to switch to root then system ask for Root user password.But when i enter same command with SUDO, like sudo su then my user switches to Root user and don't ask for Root user Password.

Tested on Ubuntu and Fedora, same behavior on both platform.

Comment: Have you run *sudo -k* before?

Comment: Please move this to SuperUser.

Comment: Hey i am new to stackoverflow please tell how to move to superuser.

Comment: It's ok, when more people vote to move this to SuperUser, it'll be done automatically. With your current previlages, you cannot move it yourself.

Comment: Hey @wonce i have run sudo -k before running sudo su but same behavior.

Comment: Is your question about sudo not asking the root password or not any password at all?

Comment: Let me clear, Have password for root user and another user too. But in terminal when i type su command to acquire root user terminal then system as for Root user password. and if i type sudo su command from terminal to switch from sudo user to root user system don;t ask root user password and i get root shell and it won't prompt for Root password.

Comment: @wonce The OP wants to require the root password for the root shell, so that he can let users run selected things as root but not get a root shell. As mentioned in my answer, achieving this is quite tricky because many commands allow shellouts.

Comment: Yes @ChrisJester-Young i want exactly you have mentioned in your comment, i don't want sudo user to get a root shell, for security reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`su` will only ask for the root password if it's not already being run as root. `sudo su` runs `su` as root, by definition.

If you set up a user in `sudoers` without a command whitelist, you are giving that user free access to run anything as root. Don't be surprised for them to get a root shell without the root password. Also, restricting `su` via a command blacklist won't help either; there are many other ways to get a root shell. Whitelisting is your only defence.

(Blacklisting == user can do everything except X, Y, and Z. Whitelisting == user can only do X, Y, and Z.)

Comment: can you please tell me how to add these to sudoers file or how to add Blacklisting. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: A usual `sudoers` line looks like this: `user = (ALL : ALL) ALL`. This means that the given user can run any command, as any user or any group. The final `ALL` there (outside of parentheses) is the command list. You need to replace that with the list of commands you will allow the user to run. Choose the commands carefully, for even simple commands like `less` will permit shellouts.

Comment: Please can you provide me exact change i have to change in file to achieve what i want to do,because when i replace ALL with command, terminal lock user from running any command i get error.

Comment: What commands do you want them to be able to run? Be specific.

Comment: I want them to run all command possible for a sudo user, but when they run sudo su command to switch from sudo root, system should ask root user password. So if they don't know root user password. then they can't get a root Shell.

Comment: "All" commands? Try this: `sudo less /etc/passwd` (or another file; the specifics don't matter). Then press `!`, then enter. Instant root shell. That is what a shellout is. Many commands that users can run provide such capabilities. Or, how about... `sudo sh`? `sudo bash`? `su` is not your only problem.

Comment: They can just run `sudo bash` to get a root shell. Or they can use `sudo -s`. I've never understood the idiom `sudo su`, I think people type if because of the alliteration.

Comment: @Barmar I actually detest `sudo su`, I prefer to use `sudo -i` or `sudo -s` as appropriate. :-)

Comment: Ohh ok now understand su is not only problem, i am getting a root shell with step you mentioned. So it is not possible to have what i want for sudo to as password before getting root user shell.

Comment: Hey @Barmar you can't teach everyone in your organization how one can fire a command. but problem here is how to not allow sudo user to get root shell without root user password.

Comment: @user3259496 Right, in vanilla Unix (without using capabilities or such like), you either trust someone to do a small set of tasks (in which case, it's best to write scripts to perform those tasks, and put _only_ those scripts in the command whitelist), or else you trust them with the world. Those are really your only options.

Comment: I can understand his wish. If users have to fire each command separately, they all get logged. But if they can get a shell, the log just has the initial shell invocation, and nothing that they do within the shell is logged. Unfortunately, there's no feasible way to implement this.

Comment: @Barmar There's really no easy way to win, short of whitelisting (and even that is tricky). Many years ago, before I realised the wisdom of this, I tried writing a logging shell that only allowed a whitelist of commands (but still allowed `cd` and redirections to work), and to this day I still have no idea if my whitelist is tight enough to avoid shellouts. I have come to learn, at the end of the day, "it's trust or bust".

Comment: My wish is, in my system i have many user with sudo privileges,all have there password,but i don't want to them to get ROOT user shell in  any case without having to know root user password. but sudo su command allow a sudo user to get ROOT user shell without entering Root user password.But if sudo user enter fire su command to become superuser then system as for root user password.

Comment: There is "a" solution, but it's totally overkill. You use `ptrace` to monitor for all `execve` system calls and log them. But your logs will be flooded with useless crap when you run shell scripts....

Comment: Here's another overkill solution. Set up LXC containers or something similar, one for each user. They can have root there to their heart's content. These containers talk to the main system via Unix-domain sockets (or even TCP/IP sockets, but that's even more overkill). Log everything coming through these sockets. You have to write a daemon to listen on that socket and process/log requests.

Comment: I still not got my answer and Question is kept On Hold.. Nice...

Comment: @user3259496 Has it occurred to you that a satisfactory answer to your question is impossible, due to the design inherent in both Unix and `sudo`? The best answer I have for you is, if you can't trust your users, then do _not_ allow them to run anything untrusted. And the list of untrusted programs is very, very long....

Comment: No answer or comment is satisfactory. @ChrisJester-Young consider if you are server administrator, and you are the only person who have ROOT access and root password, and you have another sudo user in linux for your assistance, he don't know root password, but he can access root shell do what ever he want,If something goes wrong then you are responsible persons, because log will show that all shit happen with root user.

Comment: @user3259496 Then don't give sudo access to the other users. Simple. Or else, figure out what commands are safe for them to run, and allow them _only_ those commands.

Comment: but i don't understand why question is on Hold. Let others have there opinion..

Comment: @user3259496 It's on hold pending migration to Super User. Well, assuming the Super User mods want it migrated there. Also, Stack Exchange is not for opinions. Certainly what I stated is not opinions per se. They are actual observations based on my understanding of Unix's security model. And I don't think you're likely to find someone who has a different but still correct view of Unix security.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisJester-Young this my first question on Stackoverflow. and very new to it. i truly appreciate your work because you are the one who understood my exact problem.